# How do I know when an EC2 instance dehibernation is completed and the instance is ready to use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-php-sdk

I'm starting an hibernated EC2 instance with the following:

```
$result = $client->startInstances([
    'InstanceIds' => [
        'i-1234567890abcdef0',
    ], ]);
```

How can I create a synchronous call, and continue code execution only when the instance is ready to use ?

Comment: You can use `Amazon EventBridge` and `lambda` for this purpose. When the state of the EC2 chnages to `running`, the lambda is executed which in turn execute your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a waiter: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_waiters.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2016-11-15.html#waiters

```
$result = $client->startInstances([
    'InstanceIds' => [
        'i-03e66267490433933',
     ], 
]);

$client->waitUntil(
      "InstanceRunning", 
      ['InstanceId' => 'i-1234567890abcdef0']
);

// continue execution here
```